# aws apigateway base path mapping and javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, aws-api-gateway

I have the following base path mapping for a custom domain:

```
$ aws apigateway get-base-path-mapping \
> --domain-name <my-domain-name> \
> --base-path "(none)"
{
    "basePath": "(none)", 
    "restApiId": "<my-rest-api-id>", 
    "stage": "dev"
}
```

But the base url in my downloaded javascript sdk is like this:

```
var invokeUrl = 'https://<my-domain-name>null';
```

*(Note the appended 'null')*

I figured I could change the base path from '(none)' to '/' (or even to ''), but that isn't allowed:

```
$ aws apigateway update-base-path-mapping \
> --domain-name <my-domain-name> \
> --base-path "(none)" \
> --patch-operations op='replace',path='/basePath',value='/'

An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateBasePathMapping operation: A base path may contain only letters, numbers and one of $-_.+!*'(),
```

Any help?  Thanks.

Comment: From what I understand, You want to keep base path as empty?
If that is the case just keeping it empty will work. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-base-path-mapping.html

Comment: @PiyushAhuja, thanks for your response.  Yes, I do want the base path empty.  My only problem is that the invokeUrl in the downloaded javascript sdk file has the string "null" appended to it.   It seems like a bug in the sdk generator.  At any rate, it's not a big deal just editing it.  Thanks.

Comment: I believe if you supplied `--cli-input-json` with a JSON structure with `path` as an empty string `""` it *should* work according to the apigateway documentation, it might just be that like you said there is a quirk in the "empty" string handling and something goofy with how `"(none)" is interpreted.